# Keycloak denies access even for empty role

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-connect

In `Node.js` app I try to secure page with `keycloak.protect()`, but after successful login app always responds with `403` error.

Keycloak was configured this way:

- `Master` -> `Add realm` -> Name: `kingdom`
- `Clients` -> `Create` -> Client ID: `nodejs`
- `Clients` -> `nodejs` -> `Settings`:

  - `Access Type`: **confidential**
  - `Valid Redirect URIs`: *****

Then add `Alice` user and successfully login as that user when Keycloak asks for credentials, but then getting `Access denied` page. I've [set up project](https://github.com/SlausB/keycloak-nodejs-boilerplate) where everything might be `./run.sh` with single command. I would appreciate any tips on how Keycloak should be additionally configured.

How can I setup Keycloak properly so that access will be allowed for empty list of roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `docker`<->`keycloak-connect` misunderstanding issue: `keycloak-connect` talks to `Keycloak` directly (without issuing redirects) and when it fails (it does because `Keycloak` container isn't accessible from `Node.js` container through localhost) it issues `Access denied` response.

I specified `network_mode: host` docker setting for `Node.js` container so that `keycloak-connect` now can access `Keycloak` internally.